# How to solve the minimum value of a function without analytic expression?

Tags: numerics

The analytic expression can be obtained for **`f`**.

```
f = Integrate[AiryAi[x], x]
```

> -((x (-3 Gamma[1/3] Gamma[5/3] HypergeometricPFQ[{1/3}, {2/3, 4/3},
> x^3/9] +
> 3^(1/3) x Gamma[2/3]^2 HypergeometricPFQ[{2/3}, {4/3, 5/3}, x^3/
> 9]))/(9 3^(2/3) Gamma[2/3] Gamma[4/3] Gamma[5/3]))

Therefore, the minimum value within a certain range of **`x`** can be obtained by **`NMinimize`**.

```
NMinimize[f, {x, -8, 8}]
```

> {-0.941019, {x -> -2.33811}}

```
m = Integrate[AiryAi[x] Exp[x], x]
```

However, there is no way to find the minimum value of **`m`** (the analytic expression cannot be obtained by integration)

Is there any way to find the minimum value of **`m`** within a certain range of **`x`**? thank you.

Comment: You don't have any bounds on your `Integrate`. The minimum in either case is undefined unless you provide bounds because as you should know from calculus, the antiderivative has a $+C$ term which can be any number. I assume you mean the canonical integral from $0$ to $x$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- We calculate the integral by `f'[x] == AiryAi[x] Exp[x]` and `f[0]=Integrate[AiryAi[x] Exp[x], {x, -∞, 0}]`
- To calculate `f[c]` we using `ParametricNDSolveValue` in the neighbourhood of `c`,that is `{c-1,c+1}`.

```
Clear[int, sol, min];
int = Integrate[AiryAi[x] Exp[x], {x, -∞, 0}];
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'[x] == AiryAi[x] Exp[x], f[0] == int},
    f, {x, c - 1, c + 1}, {c}];
min = NMinimize[sol[c]@c, {c}]
Plot[sol[c]@c, {c, -10, 10}, Mesh -> {{c /. min[[2]]}}, 
 MeshStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[10],  Red}]
```

[image]

Comment: We can get all of the minima by setting `C[1]` be a odd number. `extremum = Solve[{Exp[x] AiryAi[x] == 0}, x, Reals][[1]];
D[Exp[x] AiryAi[x], x] > 0 /. extremum /. C[1] -> # & /@ {1, 3, 5, 7, 
  9, 11, 13}`

Comment: You can use `FindMinimum` instead.

Comment: @TheDoctor  No. We want to find the `Global` minimum, we cann't assuming `-10<x<10` or using `FindMinimum`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you are integrating from $0$ to $t$ and ignoring the $+c$ term that should be present in any antiderivative. In that case, you can just solve when the derivative equals zero (and check the 2nd derivative is positive):

```
m = Integrate[AiryAi[x] Exp[x], {x,0,t}]
mint = t /. First@Solve[D[m,t] == 0, t];
Reduce[(D[m, {t, 2}] /. t -> AiryAiZero[1]) > 0]
minval = N[m /. t -> mint]
```

The minimum value occurs at `t == AiryAiZero[1]` which is approximately -2.33811. And the minimum is `N[Integrate[AiryAi[x] Exp[x], {x, 0, t}] /. t -> AiryAiZero[1]]` which is approximately -0.396162

Comment: If we use `{x, -Infinity, t}` as Sumit's answer assumes, then we get  a minimum value at the same `AiryAiZero[1]` point but minimum of `-0.0174104` which corroborates their answer.

Comment: `Clear[m, mint]; m = Integrate[AiryAi[t] Exp[t], t]; mint = 
 Solve[E^t AiryAi[t] == 0, t, Reals][[1]]; 
Reduce[D[m, {t, 2}] > 0 /. (mint[[1]] /. C[1] -> #)] & /@ Range[100]`

Comment: Via the first fundamental theorem the derivative of the integral is `AiryAi[t] Exp[t]` which clearly vanishes only when `AiryAi[t]==0`

Answer (score 6):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Define `m` with a numeric integral

```
m[t_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[AiryAi[x] Exp[x], {x, -Infinity, t}]

{min, arg} = NMinimize[m[t], t]

(* {-0.0174104, {t -> -2.33811}} *)

Plot[m[t], {t, -10, 10},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[{t, min} /. arg]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `NIntegrate`—which has to compute the integral *separately* for each value of `t`— one can use the *exact* integral 

`y0 = Integrate[AiryAi[x] Exp[x], {x, -Infinity, 0}]`

and then use `NDSolve`:

`NDSolve[{y'[x]==AiryAi[x] Exp[x], y[0]==y0, y, {x,-10,10}]`

Comment: @TheDoctor Since the goal is using `NMinimize` for all x, so we cann't assume that `-10<x<10` To speed up ,we can set `Clear[int, m]; int = 
 Integrate[AiryAi[x] Exp[x], {x, -\[Infinity], 0}]; 
m[t_?NumericQ] := 
 int + NIntegrate[AiryAi[x] Exp[x], {x, 0, t}] ; {min, arg} = 
 NMinimize[m[t], t] // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: The goal is to find the global minimum, *not* to use `NMinimize` for all x. 

Using the first fundamental theorem the derivative of the integral is `AiryAi[t] Exp[t]` which vanishes iff `t = AiryAiZero[n]`.

And, for a minimum, the second derivative is positive iff `AiryAiPrime[AiryAiZero[n]] > 0`.

Answer (score 5):

You can extract numerical data and create an interpolating function.

Here I am assuming $g(y) = \int_{-\infty}^y f(x)dx $ and using -1000 for $-\infty$. Depending on your function you may need a different limiting value.

```
int[y_] := NIntegrate[AiryAi[x] Exp[x], {x, -1000, y}]
data = Table[{y, int[y]}, {y, -10, 10, 0.1}];
f = Interpolation[data]

z0 = NMinimize[f[x], {x, -8, 8}]
```

> {-0.0174105, {x -> -2.33813}}

```
Show[ListPlot[data], Plot[f[x], {x, -8, 8}, PlotStyle -> Black],
     Epilog -> {Red, Point[{x /. z0[[2]], z0[[1]]}]} ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using:
$$\int \text{Ai}(x) \sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{x^j}{j!} \, dx=\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \int \frac{\text{Ai}(x) x^j}{j!} \, dx$$

```
f[x_, M_] := Sum[-((x^(1 + j) (-3 Gamma[(1 + j)/
    3] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{(1 + j)/3}, {2/3, (4 + j)/3},
     x^3/9] + 
  3^(1/3) x Gamma[(2 + j)/
    3] HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{(2 + j)/3}, {4/3, (5 + j)/3},
     x^3/9]))/(9 3^(2/3) j!)), {j, 0, M}]

Terms=20;(* Only 20 ! *)
NMinimize[f[x, Terms], {x, -3, 0}, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
(*{-0.39616201050130477798, {x -> -2.3381074104597670385}}*)
```